# error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a constant or a read-only property

Tags: angular, typescript

3 error display in my terminal:

1. error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'i' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
2. error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'result' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
3. error TS2322: Type '0' is not assignable to type 'void'.

**component.ts**

```
total: any;
totalPrice(): void {
      const result = 0;
      for (
        const i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++
      ) { const data = this.datas[i];
        result = result + data.total;
      }
      return result;
    }
```

**component.html**

```
<td>{{ data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.total }}</td>`

{{ totalPrice() }}
```

actually im running a list through *ngFor so the function totalPrice() is to add up all the data.total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause by variable declare with `const` is readonly. Try to change `const` to `let`, remove `: void` or change to `: number`

```
total: any;
totalPrice() {
      let result = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
        let data = this.datas[i];
        result = result + data.total;
      }
      return result;
    }
```